# SSL Causing 3 Redirects on Wordpress Site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress site that is secured by SSL. When a user navigates to my site, they are being redirected to the www non-secure URl, then the www-secure URL before finally reaching the preferred destination of the non-www secure URL. So, the redirects are:

The code in my file regarding the redirects is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxx.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC] [OR] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I am trying to reduce the redirects for the sake of optimization. Can someone please advise?

Comment: Redirect everything http to https.  Then do a redirect from www.host to host if needed.

Comment: If you don't want people using `www.example.com` then why does your first redirect send them there? Also why do you have redirect rules for `80` _and_ `!443`? Delete that second block entirely and remove the `www` from the first.

Comment: I changed the address to the non-www domain and I am still gettting the same set of redirects. And yes, the cache was cleared. I also deleted the second block entirely.